# How to add Cocoa controls inside an NSTextField?

Tags: macos, cocoa

In the OS X System Preferences, there is a pane:

[image: System preferences pane]

The blue labels are draggable, and even accept mouse clicks to display a menu.

What is the nature of these labels?

Comment: [Here](https://www.idrivesync.com/share/view?k=G8lPF2SxZ2Xjh2I9ndPg87QmknUY7xQ0) is sample code.

Comment: The content of Tokens doesn't update after mouse is released but thanks for the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for:

[NSTokenField](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTokenField_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

[Token Field Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/TokenField_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006555)